# First cin.getline skips

Tags: c++, console, cin

```
fstream file;
char *email=new char[100];
cout<<endl<<"enter email";
cin.getline(email,100);
char *password=new char[100];
cout<<endl<<"enter password";
cin.getline(password,100);
file.open("admin.txt",ios::out);
if(file.good())
{
    file<<email<<"\n";
    file<<password<<"\n";
}
cout<<"contents added";
```

The console only allows to enter one value which is saved in password variable , why?

Comment: *Hundreds* of duplicates. Please search this site a bit before asking a question.

Comment: Look at the "related" at the right now that you created the question, anyway ;)

Comment: Why are you allocating dynamically instead of using `std::string`?

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+getline+skipping

Answer (score 0):

You need to ignore the remaining characters in the input stream:

```
std::cin.getline(email, 100);
std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max() );
```

You should also be using `std::string` instead of raw pointers:

```
std::string email;
std::string password;

std::cin >> email >> password;

std::fstream file("admin.txt", std::ios_base::out);

if (file << email << password)
{
    std::cout << "Content added" << std::endl;
}
```